# Multiple instances of SendGrid on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, sendgrid

we are developing services on IBM Bluemix.  Is it possible to have multiple instances of SendGrid in a single Bluemix organization?

Comment: Yessssssssssssssss (had to have a minimum 15 character length to post)

Comment: Thanks Ben!  (I also had to stretch out my question to post... :)

Comment: Two follow-up questions: @BenRondeau
1) Can SendGrid instances be provisioned and deleted via Cloud Foundry CLI? (I assume yes.)
2) Is there a pool of instances or are they created dynamically?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) it is a third party service so not sure how instances are generated

Comment: Thanks @BenRondeau !!